# How do I code a navigation for wordpress with hover actions

Tags: php, navigation, wordpress-theming

...that pulls the first letter of the page title for Span A and the whole title for Span B (the hover result). I have the html and CSS version here http://codepen.io/CrabSmith2400/full/Kolje. I have spent hours reading through the WordPress tag list and trying things I read on Google and its been weeks now. I feel that its probably a really simple answer but I am pretty green, this is my first project and I am building it from scratch. Any advice or a point in the right direction would leave me forever in your debt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you got this piece of HTM:

```
<div>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
div, span{
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:grey;
}

div{
    position:relative;
}

span{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}

div span:first-child{
    display:block;
}

div:hover span{
    display:block;
}

div:hover span:first-child{
    display:none;
}
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mm4AL/

Comment: Thank you. I have that so it works on my mock up but how do I code the index.php / header.php tags so that in wordpress when you create a new page in the WP dashboard the Nav menu will change with it.

Comment: So say you wanted to change the name of the "P" Photo page to "C" Cinema through the dashboard WordPress would have to pull the first character for span A and the whole word for span B.

Comment: Use a combination of `substr()` (PHP)  and `the_title()` (WordPress)

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for please upvote & accept it. Thanks. :)

Comment: How do I do that? Lol, I'm a super-noob!

Comment: See the 0 with two arrows next to my answer (at the left)? Up arrow = up vote, underneath you'll find a checkmark, if you click that it means you "accept" this answer. :)

Comment: am I on the right track?

<div>
<li><a href="<?php ?>"><span><?php $short = the_title();
 echo substr($short(0)); ?> </span><span><?php echo the_title()); ?>
</span></a></li>
</div>

Comment: That's looking good, only the syntax of your `substr` is wrong. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php